# Poincaré recurrence in a closed universe?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, cosmology, entropy, poincare-recurrence

Is it possible that the Poincaré recurrence applies to a closed universe (with a finite spacetime)? If it is, would this mean that a closed universe could eventually reach the same state as its initial state (i.e. the initial state at the Big Bang)?